# Does QGIS support AWS Redshift connection?

Tags: qgis, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am planning to connect AWS Redshift using QGIS for work purposes. However, I am not sure whether I can connect or not.

Comment: can you give us a clue as to what AWS redshift is?

Comment: AWS Redshift is basically a data warehouse service in the cloud

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is a fresh pull request - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/53018